# What is the correct way to use uncompyle6 for code objects?

Tags: python

I found this example on github [(original)](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/blob/master/test/simple-uncompyle-code-test.py), but this seem be very outdated, so I changed it a bit.

```
from uncompyle6.main import decompile 
import sys

def uncompyle_test():
    gen = (expr1 if cond1 else expr2 for A in [] if (expr3 if cond2 else expr4))
    co = gen.gi_code
    decompile (3.6, co, sys.stdout, showast=False)

uncompyle_test()
```

And by running this I'm getting 
`.0A if expr3 if cond2 else expr4`.
That seems quite incorrect. Am I missing something or it's just a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, but it should give you some idea of what's going on.

First thing that should be noted is that the bytecode version passed into the `decompile()` function should be the same as the Python version you are running, because that is the kind of bytecode that is getting produced. xdis has a function to ensure that:

```
>>> from xdis.magics import sysinfo2float
>>> sysinfo2float()
3.6
```

However I'll assume that was the case.

Second, when you decompile the entire program, you get a correct result:

```
# uncompyle6 version 3.2.3
# Python bytecode 3.6 (3379)
# Decompiled from: Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  9 2018, 01:37:56) 
# [GCC 7.2.0]
# Embedded file name: exec
# Compiled at: 2018-09-18 16:10:11
# Size of source mod 2**32: 243 bytes
from uncompyle6.main import decompile
import sys

def uncompyle_test():
    gen = ((expr1 if cond1 else expr2) for A in [] if (expr3 if cond2 else expr4))
    co = gen.gi_code
    decompile(3.6, co, sys.stdout, showast=False)
```

So why doesn't what you tried work? The main problem is that uncompyle6 needs to know what kind of thing it is trying to deparse. Recall that the `compile()` function has three "modes": "exec", "eval", and "single".

From the Python documentation for [built-in function `compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#compile):

> The mode argument specifies what kind of code must be compiled; it can
> be 'exec' if source consists of a sequence of statements, 'eval' if it
> consists of a single expression, or 'single' if it consists of a
> single interactive statement

Here the context is a generator, which an eval is a kind of expression. deparse() doesn't allow you to choose which one you mean and uses "exec". At a lower level in the parse though you distinguish "exec" from "single", but there isn't currently a way to specify "eval" in general let alone in this particular function. I have opened an uncompyle6 issue to note this.

And finally, let's describe a little more about why you are seeing what you are seeing.

For that let's use this handy and unique debugger I wrote that shows you what's going on both in deparsing but more importantly here in disassembly.

```
$ trepan3k /tmp/bug.py 
(/tmp/bug.py:1): <module>
-> 1 from uncompyle6.main import decompile
Rocky's Python Trepan Python code startup loaded
(trepan3k) next 2
(/tmp/bug.py:9 @28): <module>
-- 9 uncompyle_test()
(trepan3k) step
(/tmp/bug.py:4): uncompyle_test
-> 4 def uncompyle_test():
(trepan3k) next 3
(/tmp/bug.py:7 @20): uncompyle_test
-- 7     decompile (3.6, co, sys.stdout, showast=False)
(trepan3k) disasm co
Disassembly of <code object <genexpr> at 0x7f6a3faff300, file "/tmp/bug.py", line 5>: 
   5        0 LOAD_FAST           0          .0                  
       >>   2 FOR_ITER            30         to 34               
            4 STORE_FAST          1          A                   
            6 LOAD_GLOBAL         0          cond2               
            8 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   14         to 14               
           10 LOAD_GLOBAL         1          expr3               
           12 JUMP_FORWARD        2          to 16               
       >>  14 LOAD_GLOBAL         2          expr4               
       >>  16 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   2          to 2                
           18 LOAD_GLOBAL         3          cond1               
           20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   26         to 26               
           22 LOAD_GLOBAL         4          expr1               
           24 JUMP_FORWARD        2          to 28               
       >>  26 LOAD_GLOBAL         5          expr2               
       >>  28 YIELD_VALUE         None                           
           30 POP_TOP             None                           
           32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE       2          to 2                
       >>  34 LOAD_CONST          0          None                
           36 RETURN_VALUE        None                           
(trepan3k) Leaving
trepan3k: That's all, folks...
```

So you see that the `.0` does indeed come from the code: it is a temporary variable that is used inside the generator. However there should have been some sort " for" and the "in []" is also missing. And that is missing because code somewhere else sets that part up, I think.

In sum, things are a little whacky because the top-level context is not right. A grammar rule assuming this is a single expression should have been used rather than a grammar rule for a complete program.